# Apache header remove?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers

I have a case where a customer wants to remove the SAMEORIGIN header and add ALLOW-FROM. This is Apache 2.22

I have done this in both the http:// and https:// configurations:

> Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM ..."

When I curl the http:// url I see only the ALLOW-FROM, not the SAMEORIGIN header. However, curling the https:// url it still adds the SAMEORIGIN header before the ALLOW-FROM. I have checked in the global apache confs and the site .htaccess and cannot find where this is being forced.

I have also tried first unsetting the headers and then setting the ALLOW-FROM in both the https:// conf and .htaccess.

Where else might I look?

Comment: You should no ALLOW-FROM has pretty poor browser support: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options/#X-Frame-Options-Browser-Support

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There are some php configuration files buried within the site code that are forcing sameorigin.